# legal disclaimers and lisence type for a free multiplayer browser game

Tags: legal, browser-based-games

I have created a multiplayer browser game. The game is completely free (donations are welcome) but I would like:

(a) to protect my concept in some way. 
(b) to provide legal notes that the user should accept before registering.

In some games (i.e. Travian) there are legal notes such as `Terms and Conditions`, `Privacy Policy`. Should I include things like these? Where can I get/create such legal texts? I can barely afford hosting, not to mention a lawyer to write all those things for me.

What should I do?

Chris

Answer (score 2):

You can protect yourself with disclaimers (Not responsible for lost work, time, nerves,...) but protecting the concept (=idea) is impossible. The good news (or bad, depending on your skills) is, that idea is only a small portion of success. It's execution that matters.

Answer (score -2):

Protecting your concept, at least in the US and most other countries (I see from your profile you're in Greece) is simply a matter of sticking `Copyright <Name> <Date>` on your game/website somewhere.  Without hiring a lawyer, that's about the best you can do (then just hope that no one else steals your concept from you...)

As for `Terms and Conditions` and `Privacy Policy`, it's a good idea to include something like them, mostly since they are there to protect you from getting sued by someone.  There's generic versions of these out there on the internet, just do a search.  A generic version probably won't be quite as good as something written for you by a lawyer, but it should cover the basics at least.

Obligatory "I am not a lawyer, rules vary by country, this isn't legal advice" text here.

Comment: Copyright notes are optional. They are not required for copyright to be valid.